# How to read dictionaries in list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to read some JSON for a leaderboard for my discord bot, formatted like this:

```json
{"915714438273826858": 
    [
        {"915714438823313420": 
                ["", 0]
        }, 
        [
            {"747797252105306212": 
                [1, 2]
            },
            {"695390884291674153": 
                [3, 8]
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

I can read the first part fine, but reading this list here is giving me some problems:

```json
[
    {"747797252105306212": 
        [1, 2]
    },
    {"695390884291674153": 
        [3, 8]
    }
]
```

How can I read the values of each of the dictionaries in the list? For example, say I want to get the dictionary with the key `"747797252105306212"`'s sub-list, so I could get `[1,2]`?

Currently, my method is to get all the keys in the larger list using

```py
all_keys = set().union(*(d.keys() for d in lb))
all_keys = list(all_keys)
```

and then using the order in `all_keys` to call the dictionary. For example, sometimes, all_keys shows `["747797252105306212","695390884291674153"]`, and I can call the dictionaries using the above order, as `"747797252105306212"`'s index is `0` in both `all_keys` and in the JSON list. However, sometimes `all_keys` is out of order, making the program call the wrong dictionary, causing this method to be obsolete. Is there any way to fix this, or a different method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, the issue is that sets don't maintain insertion order.

You can maintain a list (which maintains order) and a separate set (for quickly checking whether you've seen a key already). For each key that you see, check whether it's a member of the set; if not, add it to the list and the seen keys set:

```py
result = []
seen_keys = set()
for item in data:
    for key in item:
        if key not in seen_keys:
            seen_keys.add(key)
            result.append(key)
            
print(result)
```

With the given data, this will (deterministically!) output:

```py
['747797252105306212', '695390884291674153']
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! This looks like what I wanted, and I will test it when I get a chance.

Comment: Awesome! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Much shorter way to do an order-preserving dedupe of `x` is `[*{}.fromkeys(x)]`.

Comment: @wim it may be shorter, but in this answer I actually understand what is happening. Thanks though!

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I got to test your answer and it worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: @TheFeatherMan No problem, happy to help!

Comment: @wim -- what would `x` be in this case?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark Anything iterable that you want to dedupe.

Comment: @wim I like your shorter way, and just to make it (potentially) easier to understand for the uninitiated, I would like to point out that it can also be done like this: (1) `[*dict.fromkeys(x)]`, (2) `list({}.fromkeys(x))` or (simplest of all) (3) `list(dict.fromkeys(x))`.